# how to make vim vundle install plugin to another path

Tags: vim

By default, vundle install vim plugins to ~/.vim/bundle/ on linux machine.

How can I make it install plugins to:

```
~/here/please/vundle/install/all/plugins/
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be as simple as passing the target directory to the `rc()` function when you set up vundle.  The implementation of that function explains it well enough if you know a bit of vimscript:

```
func! vundle#rc(...) abort
  let g:bundle_dir = len(a:000) > 0 ? expand(a:1, 1) : expand('$HOME/.vim/bundle', 1)
  let g:vundle_log = []
  call vundle#config#init()
endf
```

Instead of just calling

```
call vundle#rc()
```

in your vimrc, use

```
 call vundle#rc("~/here/please/vundle/install/all/plugins")
```

Comment: It works. And I use this: `call vundle#rc("$HOME/here/please/vundle/install/all/plugins")`   -- the **$HOME** and **~** both expanded to home directory, I found it good to try another when one get strange warning.

Comment: Added to [Vundle FAQ](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/wiki#how-do-i-make-vundle-install-plugin-to-another-path)